# How to manipulate the data of a query via JSON?

Tags: node.js

I'm using a third-party API (so far so good, I get the result), however as I'm new I'm having difficulty manipulating these results for the frontend (EJS)** ...

*What the system should do is:*

The site is a graphics panel, where I use the third-party API (it blocks the origin if consumed by the frontend) and I populate the data received in JSON, using the graphics plugin called (CHARTJS) .. The problem is there, because the API should be consumed as soon as the page is accessed and the graphics populated after consumption, but for me to consume this JSON I need to pass some QS ... These QSs when accessing the page for the first graphic are already automatic and can be manipulated by the form that contains the same page, in order to be able to carry out other queries ..

I am totally, lost, I would love some help and explanation ..

**CONTROLLERS/LOGIN/LOGIN.JS**

```
module.exports.index = (_application, _request, _response) => {
    _response.render('login/index');
}

module.exports.check_login =  (_application, _request, _response) => {
    const JSON_MODEL = new _application.app.models.jsonDAO('fatVenda.xsjs', '\'BSC\'', '201807', 'vendaabs,vendam2');
    JSON_MODEL.request();

    console.log(JSON_MODEL.jsonData)

    const VENDA_MODEL = new _application.app.models.vendaDAO('', '', '', '');

    _response.render('home/home');

}
```

**ROUTES/LOGIN/LOGIN.JS**

```
module.exports = (_application) => {
    _application.get('/login', (_request, _response) => {
        _application.app.controllers.login.login.index(_application, _request, _response);
    });

    _application.post('/check_login', (_request, _response) => {
        _application.app.controllers.login.login.check_login(_application, _request, _response);
    });
}
```

**MODELS/JSONDAO.JS**

```
const REQUEST = require('request');

class JsonRequestDAO {
    constructor(_xjs, _shoppingID, _periodUntil, _kpi){
        this.xjs         = _xjs;
        this.shoppingID  = _shoppingID;
        this.periodUntil = _periodUntil;
        this.kpi         = _kpi;
    }

    request(){
        REQUEST.get({
            uri: `URL${this.xjs}`,
            json: true,
            qs: {
                Shop:       this.shoppingID,
                PeriodoAte: this.periodUntil,
                Kpi:        this.kpi
            },
            headers: {
                Authorization:   'Basic KEY',
                ApiKey:          'KEY', 
                'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
                'Content-Type':  'application/json',
            }
        }, (_error, _response) => {
           (_response.statusCode == 200) ? _response.body : console.log(_error);
        });
    }
}

module.exports = () => { return JsonRequestDAO; }
```

**MODELS/VENDADAO.JS**

```
class VendaDAO {
    constructor(_shoppingName, _yearMonth, _competence, _sale, _salePercentage, _saleSquareMeter, _salePercentageSquareMeter){
        this.shoppingName              = _shoppingName;
        this.yearMonth                 = _yearMonth;
        this.competence                = _competence;
        this.sale                      = _sale;
        this.salePercentage            = _salePercentage;
        this.saleSquareMeter           = _saleSquareMeter;
        this.salePercentageSquareMeter = _salePercentageSquareMeter;
    }

    static get shoppingName()              { return this.shoppingName;              }
    static get yearMonth()                 { return this.yearMonth;                 }
    static get competence()                { return this.competence;                }
    static get sale()                      { return this.sale;                      }
    static get salePercentage()            { return this.salePercentage;            }
    static get saleSquareMeter()           { return this.saleSquareMeter;           }
    static get salePercentageSquareMeter() { return this.salePercentageSquareMeter; }
}

module.exports = () => {
    return VendaDAO;
}
```

[image]

Comment: You should remove the API authentication keys from your post.

Comment: Now you should invalidate any API authentication keys that was exposed